# How to make an object bend in the opposite direction as it moves into Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to move a 3D object like in the "Run sausage" game.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQa5PUlSfwk
There, as the character runs forward, its body kind of bends backwards, in the direction opposite to the movement.
In particular I do a simulation of a tornado in Unity, but when I want to go forward to the upper part of the tornado moved back, and after 1 second reaches the lower part ("legs")
Any suggestions would help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The movement like in the `Sausage Run` game can be achieved easily by using animator controller specifically `Blend Tree`. Watch this tutorial is you are not already familiar with these

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-zQw4GabKw

Comment: Yes, this could help me. But it is still not clear to me how to move a certain part of the body in the opposite direction from the character movement, so that after a certain delay it returns to its normal position. But thanks for the help anyway, I will try.